# Attribute set to None while running method

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, nonetype

I'm making a chess program in livewires, and when I try to run a function, an attribute (which is supposed to hold an object) gets suddenly set to None. Here is a snippet of the problem-causing methods in my code:

```
from livewires import games
....
def toggle(self):
    piece = self.hold
    ...
    elif piece.type == "K":
            if "CASTLE_R" in piece.moveset:
                 #piece is still an object, i used print
                 piece.hasmoved = True 
                 #piece still an object
                 self.boxremove() 
                 ...

def boxremove(self):
    piece = self.hold
    #suddenly piece is not an object
    print self.hold
    for item in piece.poss: #here it says an error that piece is NoneType
        item.destroy()
        ...
```

I'm confused as to why it suddenly becomes a NoneType, because I don't do anything to edit it between these parts.

The full code can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzhq9fek7qtzims/chess.py?dl=0
around line 210.

Comment: Did you try running it in the debugger?

Comment: @Selcuk yeah, but it crashes for some reason while in the livewires module.

Comment: There are places in your code that set it to `None`. Have you done any debugging to see if any of those statements are being called? If you can't get the debugger to work, adding a few print statements can be very enlightening.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've tried that too, and it seems to turn it to None the moment the boxremove() function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you set `self.hold = None` in your class `__init__`. That means there is a place/case in which it is never set, and remains `None` until your error point. You will have to debug in a larger section of code than what you have shown to find the problem.